# Predefined event message for 3D images: change slice

Tags: events, multidimensional-array, dm-script

Is there a predefined event message for 3D images when a user changes the slice?

The ROI_changed event does not trigger on a slice change.
The data_changed event does not trigger on a slice change either.

I see event messages for slices in line plots but not for 3D data.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event is called `slice_changed` and is an ImageDisplay event.
While the documentation doesn't mention the 3D images, it is still the event in the ImageDisplays that is triggered here as well.

See example:

```c
class CSliceChangeTest{
    void OnSliceChanged( object self, Number disp_flags, ImageDisplay disp, Number flags1, Number flags2, object slice_id_beg, object slice_id_end )    {
        number start, end
        disp.ImageDisplayGetDisplayedLayers( start, end )
        result("\n Slice changed:["+start+"-"+end+"]")
    }

    void Do(object self){
        image test:=RealImage("TestStack",4,400,400,5) = random()
        test.ShowImage()
        imageDisplay disp = test.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
        disp.ImageDisplayAddEventListener(self,"slice_changed:OnSliceChanged" )         
    }
}

Alloc(CSliceChangeTest).Do()
```